# Difference between math.exp(2) and math.e**2

Tags: python, math, exponent

While programming I noticed a difference between the result of math.exp(2) and math.e**2. As you can see below, this difference does not arise when calculating e^1.

Not being an experienced programmer, I wondered why this differs?
I assume it has something to do with rounding up. The python docs say that `math.exp(x)` return `e**x`, but this appears not to be precisely correct. So how come that the `math.exp(x)` operation differs from `math.e**x`?

```
>>> math.exp(1)
2.718281828459045
>>> math.e**1
2.718281828459045
>>> math.exp(1)==math.e**1
True
>>> math.exp(2)
7.38905609893065
>>> math.e**2
7.3890560989306495
>>> math.exp(2)==math.e**2
False
>>> math.exp(100)
2.6881171418161356e+43
>>> math.e**100
2.6881171418161212e+43
>>> math.exp(100)==math.e**100
False
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15322395/1639625 My guess: `math.exp` is implemented in `c` (or even in hardware) and thus has slightly different floating point behaviour.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  There's more going on here than simply "floating-point is inaccurate".  In particular, as the two answers explain, there are good reasons to expect `exp(x)` to be more accurate than `e**x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's different due to differences in the implementation of the functions. Neither one is perfect due to the nature of floating point.

The `**` operator is implemented in [floatobject.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5051533e1a16/Objects/floatobject.c#l644) and contains a lot of special cases, but none of them are invoked here, so it ultimately reaches the standard C `pow` function. The [math.pow](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5051533e1a16/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1845) function ultimately does the same thing.

The `exp` function is a straightforward wrapper around the C function of the same name, defined with a macro in [mathmodule.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5051533e1a16/Modules/mathmodule.c#l976).

As it happens, exp is more precise (both of the results match, to within the precision allowed by floating point, high-precision answers I calculated in bc). Most likely it is because internally to pow, it is calculating the extended-precision logarithm of the double-precision `e` value you pass as the first argument, which is slightly smaller than 1.

---

The fundamental issue is that `math.e`, which is the number you're calculating the power of, is:

```
2.718281828459045 09079559829...
```

Whereas the real value of *e* is

```
2.718281828459045 23536028747...
```

And this error is compounded when you use `pow` or `**`, whereas it may not be (or may be using a higher precision value internally) if you're using `exp` due to the details of the algorithms it uses.

Comment: For my understanding: what is bc?

Comment: @rosie2go It's an arbitrary-precision command line calculator for unix and linux systems - since it's arbitrary precision I can set it to calculate to 50 digits and compare that result with the python float result.

Comment: So the integer 1 becomes 0.9999999999999999468198834395860075119344401173293590545654296875 when you change it to be a float?

Comment: @rosie2go No, the point is that `e` has become a slightly smaller number, and that number's logarithm is therefore not equal to 1. And the value I listed before was a C long double, not a python float. I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 7):

`exp(x)` is implemented at a much lower level than `e**x`.  It is essentially a wrapper for a function in libc.  Said function is probably (at some level) using the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion to calculate the value directly (or possibly some other mathematical method, I'm not sure).

On the other hand, `e**x` is taking a number and raising it to a power.  This is an entirely different strategy, and probably less precise in most circumstances.  Raising numbers to powers is difficult to do precisely.